# Android Floating action button, how to use it based on screen jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button, scaffold

I have on floating action button for different screens using scaffold jetpack compose, how will I know the current screen which clicked the FAB to do a certain action. Because for every screen the action is different.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun AppLayout(
    bottomBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable () -> Unit = {}
) {

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier,
        bottomBar = { bottomBar() },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                containerColor = appColors.primary,
                shape = CircleShape,
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier,
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, null,tint = Color.White)
            }
        }
    ) { safePadding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(

                bottom = safePadding.calculateBottomPadding()

            )
        ) {
            content()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you can do hoisting on click event using lamdas to the parent right?

Comment: the same way you use to decide what screen to display inside `content`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to record the `router` of different pages：

```
var recordRouter by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
```

Switch to a different page and update the `recordRouter` value.

When the `FloatingActionButton` is clicked, determine which page the recordRouter belongs to, and then trigger the corresponding event method